# Adding 2 lists to a dictonary in a loop in Python

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I've been trying for a while to add 2 lists into my dictonary which i've created. The problem is though, that i want to run them into a loop so the first dictonary gets run 10 times and the second only one time.
Let me show you my code

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list2 = ["Heart", "Spade", "Clubs", "Diamond"]

i = 0
k = 0
while i < len(list2):
    while k < len(list1):
        dictonary = dict(zip(list1, list2))
        k = k+1
    i = i+1
print(dictonary)
```

The output im getting is:

```
{1: 'Heart', 2: 'Spade', 3: 'Clubs', 4: 'Diamond'}
```

I cant understand why it wont print out

```
{1: 'Heart', 2: 'Heart', 3: 'Heart' etc...}
```

I know my loop works fine, but i might missunderstand the concept of adding two lists together to a dictonary?
Would appreciate some help here.
Thanks!

Comment: wait, what output were you expecting? The list lengths differ, what value should be assigned to `list1`s items from `5` until `10`?

Comment: As i wrote above, i was expecting it to go through the loop of list1 10 times before it went into the second iteration of list2

Comment: It does go through it `10` times (`print(k)` and see); after that it doesn't enter the second while loop again because the condition `while k < len(list1)` is not `True` anymore.

Comment: It does not go through it 10 times, i printed(k), see for youself.. It goes only through 4 times!

Comment: No, `i` is `4`, `k` is incremented in the nested while loop and is equal to the size of `list1 + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do won't work with a dictionary anyway.

The code can be fixed a bit

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list2 = ["Heart", "Spade", "Clubs", "Diamond"]
dictonary={}
i = 0
k = 0
print(len(list2))
while i < len(list2):
    k=0
    while k < len(list1):
        print(dictonary)
        dictonary[list1[k]]=list2[i]
        k = k+1
    i = i+1
```

But you overwrite the values for the dictionary keys with each iteration of the outer loop. So the final contents of dictonary is {1: 'Diamond', 2: 'Diamond', 3: 'Diamond' etc...}

I think what you're trying to achieve can be done with a list of paired values:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list2 = ["Heart", "Spade", "Clubs", "Diamond"]
dictonary=[]
i = 0
k = 0
print(len(list2))
while i < len(list2):
    k=0
    while k < len(list1):
        print(dictonary)
        dictonary.append([list1[k],list2[i]])
        k = k+1
    i = i+1
```